# Intellij IDEA + FTP?

Tags: java, ide, ftp, intellij-idea

I'm running Intellij IDEA 10.5 and I've set up my default ftp server (File|Settings|Deployment),
but when I'm right-clicking on my project I still see Deployment option inactive (see below):


[image]

I'm new to IDEA, so I'm sure that it is not a bug, but my misunderstanding of
how one should enable ftp deployment in IDEA.
What should I do to enable it?

Please, give me a clue to solve this problem!
This is the only remaining thing that keeps me from
using IDEA instead of Eclipse in my development.

Comment: Do you run the latest IDEA version? Does it happen with IDEA 11 EAP as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to make sure that the path mappings are correctly entered in the "Mappings" tab of your deployment configuration. 
If the mappings tab is not correctly filled out, a warning will be shown in that tab (e.g. "Deployment path is not specified").

The upload/compare/download menu entries for the deployment configuration will be greyed out as long as the mappings are not defined.

I had the same problem and it was resolved by entering the correct path mappings.

Answer (score 3):

Deployment is only available in the paid ultimate edition:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/deployment.html

I'll bet you're using the free community edition.

Comment: So does WebServices feature. As they are visible in the menu, @tsds is already using the Ultimate Edition.